# Oracle in linux container unable to allocate shared memory

Tags: oracle, docker

I've been trying to run Oracle DB 12. on docker on linux, but it fails to start showing this error:

```
$ docker run -it --rm=true --name ORCLCDB -p 1521:1521 store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
...
ORA-04031: unable to allocate 40 bytes of shared memory ("shared pool","SELECT
DECODE(null,'','Total...","SQLA","tmp"
```

I've seen similar issues appearing for those running on Mac/Windows and the VM not having enough memory. On linux there's no VM and have enough free memory and hard drive:

````
$ docker stats
CONTAINER ID        NAME                CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT   MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
2f3afa902836        ORCLCDB             0.46%               255.5MiB / 125.7GiB   0.20%               1.43kB / 0B         9.8MB / 6.49MB      48```
````

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `--shm-size` option of `docker run` https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources

Comment: Good shout. It appears referenced in https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/FAQ.md#error-the-container-doesnt-have-enough-memory-allocated-a-database-xe-container-needs-at-least-1-gb-of-shared-memory-devshm too. I've tried size of 1gb (and double checked with `df -h /dev/shm`) and 2gb but didn't make a difference.